# CASE Statement With Informix

Tags: sql, informix

I want to update a query I'm running against an Informix table and need some assistance.
I wasn't aware of the differences between SQL Server and Informix unfortunately, and got a great response [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost2010778.aspx) that doesn't work.

Basically what I want to do is create a new column called Job_Account that is blank if I returned Y in the CASE statement, or if I returned N, displays the cus_num for the record that would have returned Y.
These records will have different customer numbers, but share a cus_dun_no.
So basically if Main is N, show the main customer number (record that would have returned Y).

Results would looke like:

```
Main    Job Account cus_cus_no      cus_lkp_nm  cus_nm

Y                   6625            ABC, INC.   ABC, INC.
N       6625        6694            ABC (123)   ABC, INC.(123)
```

Here is the current query:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (
            cus_nm LIKE '%(%'
            AND cus_lkp_nm NOT LIKE '%REG%'
         )
        THEN 'N'
    ELSE 'Y'
    END AS Main
,*
FROM arrcus_rec
WHERE cus_dun_no IN (
    SELECT cus_dun_no
    FROM arrcus_rec
    WHERE cus_usg_sts = 'A'
    GROUP BY cus_dun_no
    HAVING COUNT(cus_dun_no) > 1
    )
```

Example of sample data:

[image]

You can see the sample data shows job accounts (with parentheses), and I've marked Y for the main account and N for the job accounts.

Comment: I tried to format the tabular data, but there are tabs in it and I'm not sure what's supposed to be aligned with what.  Please reformat that without any tabs so that everything lines up neatly.  You filter on a column `cus_usg_sts` that isn't shown in any of the data — that's confusing too.  Please make sure we can see a minimal set of data (say 5-10 records) with all the relevant columns and very few irrelevant columns.  It would be good to show your expected output too.

Comment: You refer to `cus_num` in the text; you show `cus_nm` and `cus_cus_no` in the sample data, either of which could be what you meant by `cus_num` (or maybe there's another column you've not shown).   This doesn't make your question any clearer.

Comment: I just didn't show more data because it is very messy, with a ton of columns.  I'm only filtering by that field.  It means usage status, showing only active customers.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You had at least two options with the `cus_usg_sts` column: remove the filter on it because it isn’t crucial to the query, or show example data for it because it was referenced. Either is acceptable. Referencing it and not showing it is a bad choice.

Comment: I updated to show the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this produces the output you're after:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN (A.cus_nm LIKE '%(%' AND A.cus_lkp_nm NOT LIKE '%REG%')
       THEN 'N'
       ELSE 'Y'
       END AS Main,
       CASE
       WHEN (A.cus_nm LIKE '%(%' AND A.cus_lkp_nm NOT LIKE '%REG%')
       THEN (SELECT B.cus_cus_no
               FROM arrcus_rec AS B
              WHERE B.cus_dun_no = A.cus_dun_no
                    -- Beware De Morgan
                AND (B.cus_nm NOT LIKE '%(%' OR B.cus_lkp_nm LIKE '%REG%')
            )
       ELSE NULL::INTEGER
       END AS Job_Account,
       *
  FROM arrcus_rec A
 WHERE cus_dun_no IN (
           SELECT cus_dun_no
             FROM arrcus_rec
          --WHERE cus_usg_sts = 'A'
            GROUP BY cus_dun_no
           HAVING COUNT(cus_dun_no) > 1
       )
```

The sub-query in the main WHERE clause produces the answer 6410981 on the data given in the image (the data with AFAKORI figuring prominently).

The second CASE expression produces the magical answer wanted.  It works out whether this row is not the main account, and runs a sub-query to get the corresponding main account, or returns `NULL::INTEGER` (a NULL cast to an integer type) if this is the main account.

For the sample data:

```
cus_cus_no  cus_lkp_nm       cus_nm                           cus_dun_no
      6625  AFAKORI, INC.    AFAKORI, INC.                       6410981
      6694  AFAKORI, (594)   AFAKORI, INC,(LBCCD-BUILDING)       6410981
      6832  AFAKORI, (596)   AFAKORI, INC.(SECURITY COMPLEX)     6410981
```

the output from the query shown is:

```
main|job_account|cus_cus_no |cus_lkp_nm .    |cus_nm                          |cus_dun_no |
   Y|           |       6625|AFAKORI, INC.   |AFAKORI, INC.                   |    6410981|
   N|       6625|       6694|AFAKORI, (594)  |AFAKORI, INC,(LBCCD-BUILDING)   |    6410981|
   N|       6625|       6832|AFAKORI, (596)  |AFAKORI, INC.(SECURITY COMPLEX) |    6410981|
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  The result you show is exactly what I want.  But when I run it I get an error saying thesubquery has not returned exactly one row.

Comment: It is easy to get the “sub query has returned more than one row” error.  I saw it once, too. Without representative data, it is hard to know what you’re running into.

Comment: If I run it filtered by the sample customer we used, it works.  Thank you.  That's great.  The rest must be something with my data? I'll have to look at it further.

Comment: I was able to use this by cleaning up some of the source data.  Thank you so much.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Great — glad to have been of assistance.  It looks like the 'ANDERSON' (drilling and manufacturing) entries share a `cus_dun_no` but are both 'main' entries — which could confuse the query.  That may be part of the cleanup you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Informix but in standard SQL there a semantic problem : `count()` on same column than the `group by` couldn't work, `Having count(cus_dun_no)>1` would be maybe always false.

It would be, but without example datas I am blind:

```
FROM arrcus_rec
WHERE cus_cus_no IN (
  SELECT cus_cus_no
  FROM arrcus_rec
  WHERE cus_usg_sts = 'A'
  GROUP BY cus_cus_no
  HAVING COUNT(cus_dun_no) > 1
)
```

Add `sql` tag please :)

Comment: Thanks. I added that.  The HAVING piece works as it is.  I'll add sample data to the original post.

Comment: Testing on Informix, the sub-query in the question works fine, producing the answer 6410981 from the sample data (the image data referencing AFAKORI) if you assume there's a column `cus_usg_sts` with the value `A` in it for each of the 3 records (or if you drop the WHERE clause).  I can't immediately think of a reason why this wouldn't be standard SQL behaviour.